# delay function starts with 2 ms then delay 1 ms

Tags: c, call, delay

I'm implementing a buzzer function that takes frequency and reciprocate it and set the input pin high with delay of half of the time and low the other half of the time to get the freq wanted,

on oscilloscope delay function works well the first second (i.e delay(2msec))and then it delay with different amount of time (i.e delay(1 msec))

```
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned short int u16;
typedef unsigned long int u32;
 void delay(u32 time_in_ms)
  {
  u32 count;
  u32 loops =((time_in_ms*1000)-21)/11;
  for(count=0;count<loops;count++)
       asm("NOP");
  }

 extern void Buzzer_buzz(u16 Copy_u8Period_in_sec,u16 Copy_u8Frequency_in_Hz){
    u16 var;
    for (var=0; var<(Copy_u8Period_in_sec*1000)/(1000/Copy_u8Frequency_in_Hz)   ; var++){

        DIO_voidWritePin(0,1);

        delay(1000/(Copy_u8Frequency_in_Hz*2));

        DIO_voidWritePin(0,0);

        delay(1000/(Copy_u8Frequency_in_Hz*2));
    }
```

In main i'm calling it:

```
void main (void){

DIO_voidInitialize();
Buzzer_voidInitialize();

while(1){
Buzzer_buzz(2,200);
 }
}
```

when i tried writing the delay with numbers (i.e delay(2.5)) it works fine..

Comment: Please explain "when i tried writing the delay with numbers (i.e delay(2.5)) it works fine".

Comment: It can be an issue of integer division

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but why don't you replace `(Copy_u8Period_in_sec*1000)/(1000/Copy_u8Frequency_in_Hz)` by `(Copy_u8Period_in_sec * Copy_u8Frequency_in_Hz)` ?

Comment: @barakmanos i meant that instead of writing:    delay(1000/(Copy_u8Frequency_in_Hz*2));  i wrote delay(2.5);

Comment: @MichaelWalz i don't know how this actually affect but that actually worked for me. LOL! :D

Comment: @N.Nasser it's just basic school math concerning fractions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the problem might be that `1000/(Copy_u8Frequency_in_Hz*2)` is rounded to integer value since you are dividing an integer by an integer. Try `1000.0f/(Copy_u8Frequency_in_Hz*2)` but only if the `delay()` function can take float as a parameter.

The second problem might be that usually (and I don't know what platform is this) the `delay` functions are not precision timing by any means. In this example it might work fine but don't rely on it being close to what You want it to be.

Comment: actually i tried what michael Walz said and it worked and i don't know how btw the delay function doesn't take float but i was expecting the whole part of the number at least